# Server 2003 IAS RADIUS -> Server 2012 AD DS

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2012

I have googled this extensively but have not been able to find a good answer. Does anyone know if ' Windows Server 2003 IAS RADIUS' will query a 'Windows Server 2012 AD DS' and be able to return the attributes correctly? This is just standard AD stuff (Remote dial-in for VPN authentication).

I am hypothesizing that it will work OK, but I wanted to see if anyone had any first hand knowledge. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work just fine, though I would *strongly* recommend upgrading from Server 2003 IAS to Server 2012 or 2012 R2 NPS, which is the replacement for IAS and does RADIUS. Server 2003 is *quickly* approaching its end of life date.